# How to add more cowbell?

Tags: audio, algorithms, sound

Remember that Christopher Walken skit on Saturday Night live where he told the band “it needs more cowbell” https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/More_cowbell ?  This site automated it http://www.morecowbell.dj/ using echonest http://developer.echonest.com/ .  That’s all fine.  Question is: “What is the actual algorithm behind the beat detection and cowbell insertion?”

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The beat and onset detection algorithms used at the Echo Nest are probably variants/improvements of the techniques developed by Tristan Jehan [in his Ph.D](http://web.media.mit.edu/~tristan/phd/dissertation/index.html). This is not the only approach, and I would recommend you to try first:

- Getting an onset detection function using spectral flux or [complex amplitude](http://www.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/legacy/dafx03/proceedings/pdfs/dafx81.pdf).
- Using [this algorithm](http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~dpwe/pubs/Ellis07-beattrack.pdf) to detect beats (you can improve it using the "comb template" method described [here](http://www.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/~markp/2007/DaviesPlumbley07-taslp.pdf) to score tempo candidates - I believe this combination of Ellis' dynamic programming approach with a more sophisticated candidate scoring function is what is used in Sonic Visualizer's default beat detection vamp plug-in).

As for adding the cowbell, I think there are a bunch of heuristics that could work. First of all, you can use the breaking down of the song into sections (as provided by the EN analyzer or by [an algorithm like this](http://www.violconsort.com/mark/IEEEASLP.pdf)), and process each section individually - to have changes in the cowbell pattern coincide with changes into chorus/verse. For each section, you can align the detected onsets on a grid of 16 or 32 sixteenth note to get a discrete representation of the onsets (a bit similar to what you would see on a drum machine or sequencer); and then average these patterns to get a summary of the rhythmic structure of the section. If the section is too chaotic - use a cowbell hit on each 4th or 8th note... Possible refinements: tune the cowbell so that it matches the key of the song, stop it in the sections that have a very low loudness...